# Silverlight application resources for global access to a singleton

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, xaml, singleton

I have a singleton which once hit will load user profile information, I want to make it an application level resource in my SL3 application so that elements across the application can bind to it.

My code version of the instantiaion is a simple

```
UserProfile x = UserProfile.GetInstance();
```

I want to be able to do this in xaml in the app.xaml file and in WPF we have the ObjectDataProvider so I can express something like

```
<ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetInstance" 
ObjectType="{x:Type local:UserProfile}" x:Key="CurrentUserProfile"/>
```

I am struggling to find the right implementation for this in SL3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you point out Silverlight doesn't have `ObjectDataProvider`.  If you need a feature it provides such as  lazy instantiation you'll need to build a class of your own to handle it.  If you don't actually need these features then simply add an instance of the `UserProfile` to `App.Resources` on start up:-

```
 private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
 {
    Resources.Add("CurrentUserProfile", UserProfile.GetInstance());
    RootVisual = new MainPage();
 }
```

Comment: I was really hoping to accomplish this in pure xaml but if I dont get a xaml based solution from someone soon then I will give you the check mark...thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Silverlight has no ObjectDataProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903925(VS.95).aspx).

That said,you can use the DataContext of your Silverlight object.....

```
Application.DataContext = UserProfile.GetInstance();
```

Comment: What happens if you then need to assign DataContext on UserControls etc to some real application data as opposed to the peripheral User info?